# Duplicate UNIQUE KEY error after ROLLBACK in MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-5, transaction, unique-constraint

I have a table like this

```
mysql> describe seudonimos;
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id_seudonimo | int(11) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| seudonimo    | varchar(45)      | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
2 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```

Let's assume that it is empty so autoincrement is 0. For example:

```
SET AUTOCOMMIT=0;
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO seudonimos (seudonimo) VALUES ('Agatha Christie');
ROLLBACK;
SET AUTOCOMMIT=1;
```

As far as I konw, the rollback does not affect the autoincrement. So if I insert a new value the autoincrement will be 2 instead of 1. But if I try to insert 'Agatha Christie' again, I have the following problem:

```
INSERT INTO seudonimos (seudonimo) VALUES ('Agatha Christie');

#1062 - Duplicate entry 'Agatha Christie' for key 'seudonimo'
```

That is not what I expected. I expected this:

```
+--------------+--------------------+
| id_seudonimo | seudonimo          |
+--------------+--------------------+
|            2 | Agatha Christie    |
+--------------+--------------------+
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Questions : What version of MySQL are you using ? Can you add to the question SHOW CREATE TABLE seudonimos\G please ???

Comment: OBSERVATION Your error message says Duplicate entry for key 'seudonimo'. By any chance, is that a KEY or a UNIQUE KEY on the seudonimo field ???

Comment: Updated my answer with new observations

Comment: mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.41, for debian-linux-gnu (i486)

Comment: yes, it is a unique key, but I think the problem is that there is another table seudonimos_consulta for fullindex query and of course it is MyISAM. The data of this table is inserted, updated and deleted by a trigger. Perhaps this warning `| Warning | 1196 | Some non-transactional changed tables couldn't be rolled back | ` is suggesting that the problem is the MyISAM table. What do you think? If I am right, should I drop those triggers?

Comment: That's it. InnoDB and MyISAM operations combined can never be rolled back because once InnoDB and MyISAM join forces in queries, all tables take on the most pessimistic locking feature. InnoDB does row locking. MyISAM does table locking. Together, all tables behave as MyISAM, thus nullifying InnoDB transaction features. If the other table has FULLTEXT indexes, you must live with it and the lack of transactional behavior.

Comment: Can you post the triggers in your question ???

Comment: @RolandoMYSQLDBA, sorry, I hadn't noticed your comment before posting my answer. Here is the quote from the doc if Mario is interested: ["If you use tables that are not transaction-safe within a transaction, changes to those tables are stored at once, regardless of the status of autocommit mode."](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/commit.html)

Comment: `seudonimosAI  INSERT  seudonimos  BEGIN
      INSERT INTO seudonimos_consulta SET seudonimos_consulta.id_seudonimo=NEW.id_seudonimo, seudonimos_consulta.seudonimo=NEW.seudonimo;
     END  AFTER  NULL  NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO  root@localhost  utf8  utf8_general_ci  utf8_general_ci`

Comment: `seudonimosAU  UPDATE  seudonimos  BEGIN
       UPDATE seudonimos_consulta SET seudonimos_consulta.seudonimo=NEW.seudonimo WHERE seudonimos_consulta.seudonimo=OLD.seudonimo;
     END  AFTER  NULL  NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO  root@localhost  utf8  utf8_general_ci  utf8_general_ci
    seudonimosAD  DELETE  seudonimos  BEGIN
       DELETE FROM seudonimos_consulta WHERE seudonimos_consulta.id_seudonimo=OLD.id_seudonimo;
     END`

Comment: @Mario, this question deservers a +1 because it uncovers a MySQL gotcha in Duplicate entry errors that can eminate from triggers. Sorry, I just noticed I gave you +1 already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In one of your comments to your own question, you're saying you're using MyISAM.

However, MyISAM does not support transactions (see [ref. table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/myisam-storage-engine.html)). Therefore, it will always autocommit, whether you try to turn it off or not.

If you want to use transactions, you need to use an engine that supports it, such as InnoDB.

EDIT (following comments and additional information -- I must admit I hadn't realised you were also using a second table until @RolandoMySQLDBA pointed it out):

As the documentation says: ["If you use tables that are not transaction-safe within a transaction, changes to those tables are stored at once, regardless of the status of autocommit mode."](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/commit.html)

Since a second table (`seudonimos_consulta`, using MyISAM) is involved in the transaction, via a trigger, what's inserted after the first `INSERT` in that table isn't rolled back. Hence, `#1062 - Duplicate entry 'Agatha Christie' for key 'seudonimo'` would refer to the second table, `seudonimos_consulta.seudonimo`, not `seudonimos.seudonimo`.

Comment: You're right. But I have two tables. One of them is InnoDB, the other one is MyISAM. Of course, I was trying to use transactions with InnoDB table, but the problem is that both table are connected by triggers.

Comment: See Rolando's comment to your question. It sounds like the duplicate entry may also come from the second table you're using.

Comment: @Mario, in your error message (`#1062 - Duplicate entry 'Agatha Christie' for key 'seudonimo'`), does it say which table it comes from? From the description of your triggers, it could come from `seudonimos_consulta.seudonimo`. For debugging this, it might be interesting to rename `seudonimos_consulta.seudonimo` to something different (e.g. `seudonimos_consulta.seudonimo2`) if possible, to check which table it's referring to. I suspect that, if the `seudonimos_consulta` table is using MyISAM and there's a unique constraint on `seudonimo` there, it won't be rolled back and cause the duplicate.

Comment: Yes, the problem is that seudonimos_consulta is using MyISAM and there is a unique constraint on `seudonimo`. You are right, problem is solved. And I think I will drop MyISAM tables, and of course, its triggers, because I've found another method with temporary tables. Thank you. I'm new here. What should I do? Should I answer my own question or should I let you or Rolando answer it?

Comment: Usually, you can mark an answer as useful by clicking on the arrow/triangle pointing upwards above the vote counter left of the answer. In addition, because  you're the one who asked the question, if you think one of the answers is the right one, you can mark it as the accepted answer (with the green tick under the answer's vote counter). You can up-vote (or down-vote if it's bad) multiple answers, but you can only accept one answer. It's up to you to choose. Don't feel pressurised. There's a bit more on the point system if you expand this: http://dba.stackexchange.com/faq#reputation

Comment: @Bruno, you get a +1 from me for making a very good observation about the source of the error message because stuff was buried in the trigger behavior rather that the apparent source table. I guess MySQL (eh Oracle) should look into fixing that. What am I saying ? Is Oracle really going to fix that ?